# asp.net mvc scaffolding and GUID as the primary key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, uniqueidentifier, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have a table with the following structure

```
GUID uniqueidentifier with default value newid(), and set as primary key
ID int
Description varchar(max)
```

I created an Entity Model using visual studio, and generated the views for editing/deleting etc (mvc scaffolding)

The problem is with "Editing", when I click that link, the appropriate form is showed with the correct data, but the "save" button doesn't work at all. Please note that other links (delete,create,details) work perfectly..

So, when I click the "Edit" link, the url is

http://localhost:10871/admin/Edit/e7d0c5ee-7782-411f-920e-7b0d93c924e1

and the form is displayed correctly, but the save button doesn't work, no network activity happens. Is something particular about using uniqueidentifers as primary key?

Thanks

---Code---

**Edit.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Domain</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GUID)

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

--AdminController.cs--

// GET: /Admin/Edit/5

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
{
    Domain domain = db.Domains.Single(d => d.GUID == id);
    return View(domain);
}

//
// POST: /Admin/Edit/5

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Domain domain)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Domains.Attach(domain);
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(domain, EntityState.Modified);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(domain);
}
```

**Edit2**
In response to a comment by  ZippyV, I added the following code in Edit.cshtml

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID)
        </div>
```

to  my surprise (or ignorance) - the GUID is being shown instead of ID
[image: GUID is shown as ID]

and apart from that - when I enter a value in that field (1,2 or any integer), I still get the message "The field ID must be a number."

Comment: Maybe you could show some code? The corresponding Controller action and the view perhaps.

Comment: But of course you must define, "doesn't work."

Comment: the save button doesn't work - no network activity happens, no form is submitted, and obviously nothing is written to the database!

Comment: Have you looked at the rendered HTML? That would show you why you're not getting network activity.

Comment: Maybe validation is stopping you from submitting the form but you can't see any error because the validation failure happens on the hidden fields. Can you check the values of the hidden fields in your generated html?

Comment: Can you show the model class code which is being used on your `Edit.cshtml` page?

Comment: I changed the name of the second field in the table from ID to LID (Local ID) - and everything works just right now!! strange.. is the name ID is understood differently by the runtime??

Comment: I don't think so. I think the problem is in your Model. You may have given them different names then what you remember. Check your Model class used on the `Edit.cshtml` page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you have a property called ID on your view model:

```
public class Domain
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and at the same time you have a route parameter called `id` in your `Edit` controller action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
{
    ...
}
```

Now here's what happens: The Html helpers (such as TextBoxFor, HiddenFor, ...) always first looks in the model state when binding a value (i.e. query string parameters, route values) and only at the end it looks at the value in the model. That's how all Html helpers work and it is by design.

So you have the following:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
```

The ID is taken **NOT** from the model but from your Route data (which is a Guid as specified in your action parameter). That's why it is very dangerous to use properties in the view model and action parameters that have the same name.

One possible workaround would be to rename your action parameter to something else:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid domainId)
{
    Domain domain = db.Domains.Single(d => d.GUID == domainId);
    return View(domain);
}
```

Of course now your routes might need to be adapted or use query string parameters: `controller/edit?domainId=d578b4b7-48ec-4846-8a49-2120c17b6441` to invoke the Edit action.